# AngularJS - Sort After Data Has Been Calculated In View

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a question regarding applying math calculations on a view and sorting the values. I'm pretty sure I could do these calculations beforehand, but I was wondering if there was any way in Angular after the fact. Here's my jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7q47kv2y/2/

```
$scope.value1="true";
$scope.numbers = [3, 5, 7, 4, 5, 8]
var d = new Date();
$scope.dayofmonth = d.getDate();
```

As you can see, its just a list of numbers followed by the date of the month.

When it displays in the view, I have the number doing some math calculations. Maybe I'm missing this, but is there a way to sort these values after? Or would I need to do this all prior to showing it on the view.. The problem doing the math before is that my end goal is really is to have various math calculations preformed based on a series of checkboxes and ng-show.

IE. If a box is checked, add 5 each number, then sort.
IE. If a box isn't checked, subtract 5, etc.

Please let me know if more information is required! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built-in `orderBy` angular filter:

```
<div ng-show="value1 =='true'" 
     ng-repeat="number in numbers | orderBy:identity">
         {{number + dayofmonth + 5}}
</div>
```

**Note on `identity`:**

You'll notice that this orders by`identity`. Before Angular 1.3 you had to pass a parameter to the `orderBy` filter. On the `scope` the `identity` property is merely a reference to the angular identity function, which just returns the first argument passed in:

```
$scope.identity = angular.identity;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q47kv2y/4/)

---

**Update**

I noticed you also wanted a checkbox that determines whether to add 5 or subtract 5, so I've added another filter so you can do this operation on the same `ng-repeat` so you don't have to hide/show two sets of numbers.

HTML:

```
{{number + dayofmonth  | change:value1:5}}
```

JS (Filter):

```
angular.module('app', []).filter('change', function() {
  return function(input,positive,value) {
      return input + ((positive ? 1: -1) * value);
  };
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7q47kv2y/6/)

Comment: Really interesting about using identity! Thanks!